# Android notifications - what way should I pick for my app?

Tags: android, eclipse, notifications

My app is like Facebook. Every user has a friends list. The users can publish a status and the user's friends should get a notification immediately.
After doing some research I found out that most people recommend using GCM. I don't know if I should go in that way. First of all, I understood that I need to have an access to web resource? I really don't know what that means, can someone explain me that? Second, I realized that there is a lot of Terms for the users, like they should have a Google account and Android 2.2 or more. Isn't all that things make a big problem?
My biggest problem with GCM is that I'm noob with that kind of things and I don't think I can handle with it. Maybe Someone can show me a good tutorial? since the Android tutorial didn't really help me.
If I won't pick the GCM, there is another nice way and maybe easy of sending that kind of notifications - real time, when the database is changing? Can someone show me a tutorial?

Thank you very much, this is very important to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

I liked the tutorial hope it will be helpful.

Comment: +1 for related link, But it will be better if you can explain something in your answer.

Comment: Can you refer to the question what do I need to have for using GCM? and isn't it problem for the future users?

Comment: Thank you, this tutorial is great! Can I ask you a question about this tutorial? Do you have an email or something? I will be grateful!